# Negative Specific FilesMatch in Apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, expires-header

I want to set expiry date for all file except the 2-3 files how to use negative filematch in apache2

```
<FilesMatch "^(jquery-2.1.1.min.js|home_bg.png|jquery.ui.widget.js|jquery.placeholder.js|jquery.jscrollpane.js|jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Right now I make this happen by adding all other to file match list.

Is there anyway to use something like FilesNotMatch

```
<FilesNotMatch "^(style.css|responsive.css)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesNotMatch>
```

or something like

```
<FilesMatch "!^(style.css|responsive.css)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<FilesMatch "(?<!style\.css|responsive\.css)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: @zx81 yeah, I copypasta'ed those, should escape the `.`'s

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!(?:style|responsive)\.css).*$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You need to change those to `FilesMatch` (otherwise 500 error)

Comment: Could you explain what you did? Thanks.